# spritekitを用いたMac向けのアプリでキーボードの同時入力を処理したい

Tags: swift, spritekit

自機としてPlayerクラスのインスタンスplayerを操作しようと考えています。
WASDの４つのキーで４方に移動しますが、keyDownとkeyUpでは押している間の移動はかろうじてできるのに対し、８方向への入力、つまり同時押しによる斜め方向への移動は不可能でした。
フレームごとにキー入力が受け付けられているようなので、switch文からifで記述もしてみましたが、うまくいきません。何か良いアイデアはありませんでしょうか。

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    if event.keyCode == 13 {
        player.moveUp(distance: 10)
    }
    if event.keyCode == 0 {
        player.moveLeft(distance: 10)
    }
    if event.keyCode == 1 {
        player.moveDown(distance: 10)
    }
    if event.keyCode == 2 {
        player.moveRight(distance: 10)
    }
}
```

以上がkeyDownの中身です。
なお、PlayerクラスはmoveRight, moveLeft ...などのメソッドを持っていて、同名の関数などもありましたがoverrideはしておりませんので独自の関数です。
また中身は単純でPlayerのpositionの値をdistance（引数）に応じて動かすだけです

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今の処理方法ですと、１つのキーイベントが来たときに、そのイベントが来る度に処理をする方法になっているため、`keyDown`の中で移動を行うのはかなり難しいと思います。

多分`SKView`のサブクラスで処理を書かれていると思うので、そのクラスにX移動量とY移動量のメンバー変数を追加し、

- `KeyDown`, `KeyUp`イベントで行うのは移動量変数の更新のみ
- 実際の移動処理はタイマーを使って定期的に行う
- `moveXXX`関数は一つに纏め、`move(x: X座標移動量, y: Y座標移動量)`とする

と言う風に考えると、move関数以外の書き替え、書き加えるべき部分は以下のようになると思います。

- 更新頻度を20fps (1000ms / 20 = 50)と考えていますので、この辺りは適宜調整して下さい
- タイマーの初期化を一番省略した形で行っているので、細かい設定を行いたい場合は、`DispatchSource.makeTimerSource()`の引数を適宜設定して下さい
- 関数`move`は引数に移動量を受けとっていますが、引数無しで、直接メンバー変数を参照しても良いです

```swift
private var distanceX: Int = 0
private var distanceY: Int = 0
private var moveHandlingTimer: DispatchSourceTimer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource()

deinit {
    moveHandlingTimer.cancel()
}

override func viewDidLoad () {
    // 他の必要な処理
    moveHandlingTimer.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
        guard let weakSelf = self, let x: Int = weakSelf.distanceX, let y: Int = weakSelf.distanceY else { return }
        if ((x != 0) || (y != 0)) {
            weakSelf.move(x: x, y: y)
        }
    }
    moveHandlingTimer.schdule(deadline: DispatchTime.now(), repating: DispatchTimeInterval.miliseconds(50), leeway: DispatchTimeInterval.miliseconts(1))
    moveHandlingTimer.resume()
}

override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    switch event.keyCode {
    case 13:
        distanceX = 10
    case 1:
        distanceX = -10
    case 0:
        distanceY = -10
    case 2:
        distanceY = 10
    default:
        break
    }
}

override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {
    switch event.keyCode {
    case 13, 1:
        distanceX = 0
    case 0, 2:
        distanceY = 0
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。押した状態を取得する関数がないとわかった時にとてもヒヤッとしましたが、無事想定通りの動きを実装できました。