# SpriteKitにおいてキーボード入力を同時に２つ以上受け付ける方法を知りたい

Tags: swift4, spritekit

[spritekitを用いたMac向けのアプリでキーボードの同時入力を処理したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/57748/spritekit%E3%82%92%E7%94%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%9Fmac%E5%90%91%E3%81%91%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%81%A7%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AE%E5%90%8C%E6%99%82%E5%85%A5%E5%8A%9B%E3%82%92%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

こちらの質問に関係する話になりますので、ご参照ください。

一度は解決した問題でしたが、ここで困ったことが起こりました。
これでは確かに数値を単純にいじるだけであれば問題ないのですが、WASD移動に加えて左シフトのホールドによるスニーク（低速移動）を実装しようとした時に動作しないことは自明です。

どのようにすれば２つ以上のキーが押されている状態であるかを取得することができるのでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS 10.12 以降のみサポートで良いなら`keyDown(with: theEvent)`と`keyUp(with: theEvent)`を以下のように修正することで可能かと思います。

- `shift`で減速、`control`で加速を想定しています
- 同時押しによる衝突を避けるため、`shift`が押されていないときのみ`control`が押されているか？の判断をしています

```swift
private let DefaultSpeed: Int = 10
private let SpeedUpRate: Float = 2.0
private let SlowDownRate: Float = 0.5

override func keyDown (with event: NSEvent) {
    let accelarateRate: Float = checkAccelarateRate(for: event)

    switch event.keyCode {
    case 13:
        distanceX = DefaultSpeed * accelerateRate
    case 1:
        distanceX = -DefaultSpeed * accelerateRate
    case 0:
        distanceY = -DefaultSpeed * accelerateRate
    case 2:
        distanceY = DefaultSpeed * accelerateRate
    default:
        break
    }
}

override func keyUp (with event: NSEvent) {
    let accelarateRate: Float = checkAccelarateRate(for: event)
    if accelerateRate != 1.0 {
        distanceX = distanceX / accelerateRate
        distanceY = distanceY / accelerateRate
    }

    switch event.keyCode {
    case 13, 1:
        distanceX = 0
    case 0, 2:
        distanceY = 0
    default:
        break
    }
}

private func checkAccelarateRate (for event: NSEvent) -> Float {
    var accelerateRate: Float = 1.0
    let modifiers: NSEvent.ModifierFlags = event. modifierFlags
    if modifiers.contains(NSEvent.ModifierFlags.shift) {
        accelerateRate = SlowDownRate
    } else if modifiers.contains(NSEvent.ModifierFlags.control) {
        accelerateRate = SpeedUpRate
    }

    return accelerateRate
}
```

重複の修正漏れを予防するために、同じ意味で同じことを書いている部分の定数化、関数化を行いました。

Comment: 完璧な回答に感謝いたします。色々分割して考えなければならないのですね。これまで扱ってきたゲームエンジンではしたことのない作業で戸惑っておりました。助かります！

Comment: お役に立てたなら幸いです。同じ意味の同じ数字や、コードブロックをどちらか一つだけ修正して、残りを修正漏れでおかしな挙動にならないよう、数値リテラルの定数化、コードブロックは関数化してみました。